# Like and Send button not showing picture while posting or sending

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, facebook-social-plugins

I have added the send like and send button to a site i am working on, but i am still unable to show the image of the product that i want to share(like or send). I have added meta tags with correct image url.

Can some one help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding new, or updating existing og:meta tags you will need to run the url into the Facebook Linter @ https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
This will force Facebook to scrape the page and update the information is has on the page.  This update can only be done by an admin of the page, or is automatically done approx every 24 hours by Facebook

Comment: I did it, but it said that it is unable to download image while the link appears to be right

Comment: did you try a different image or an image in a different location?

Comment: links and image links would be useful here.